# How Apache Spark can preserve order of lines in the output textFile?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

Can anyone help me understand how `apache-spark` is able preserve the order of lines in output, when read from a textFile. Consider the below code snippet,

```
sparkContext.textFile(<inputTextFilePath>)
        .coalesce(1)
        .saveAsTextFile(<outputTextFilePath>)
```

The text file size is in GBs and I could see the data is read parallelly by worker nodes and written to the destination folder in a single file(since partition count is set to `1`). When I open the output file, I could see all the lines are in order. How does Spark acheive this ordering?

Comment: Any idea if answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee in general.

**coalesce** has optimization logic based on partition *locality*. Then, given that a large file has many partitions that may be on same worker, there is no guarantee - in order to reduce shuffling - that order is preserved. It may be in some cases so, but not always.

for parquet, orc other considerations apply, but this is a text file you state.